# How do I move to the next song using a MVVM mediaelement

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mediaelement

I'm learning C#/WPF/MVVM by building a simple media player. I am using ICollectionView in the MainViewModel for the playlist. I built a separate usercontrol for the mediaelement with some code-behind to handle the volume, position, timeline (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/smart/RSSVideoReader.aspx). I know one of the goals of MVVM is to eliminate code-behind, but the WPF mediaelement is unique. I am now stuck trying to figure how to get the code-behind mediaelement's MediaEnded event to tell the MainViewModel's ICollectionView to MoveCurrentToNext.

This code fails:

MainViewModel

```
public void GoNext()
    {
        this.collectionView.MoveCurrentToNext();
    }
```

MyMediaElement.xaml.cs (Code behind)

```
private void mPlayDefault_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        mPlayDefault.Stop();
        this.GoNext();            

    }
```

How do I get the MainViewModel to react to MyMediaElement's event? 
Thank You

Comment: This is a question more about using this particular media element.  You'll probably have to post some code, but I'm guessing only people who have used this media player would be able to help you.  Maybe post a question to the CodeProject page?

Comment: I don't agree that eliminating code-behind should be a goal when using MVVM. I think the goal should be to seperate the independent concerns of presentation (view) and behavior/mechanics (viewmodel). Thus, I wouldn't have an issue with a bit of code in the view to inform the viewmodel of a state change.

Comment: I agree Daniel, but how do I do it? What would that code look like?

Comment: Regarding the original question, you may find this blog post helpful: http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2010/11/using-eventtrigger-in-xaml-for-mvvm-no.html

Comment: Adding the dll's mentioned in the article is producing errors. Unknown build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.' I haven't found the fix at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel Pratt was correct (See Comments). Using Interaction.Triggers worked as I had hoped. I ran into a problem with the expressions dll and was totally frustrated. Downloading the dll directly from codeplex and unblocking it solved the problem. Many thanks to Daniel and Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best I could come up with:

inside of the ViewModel:

```
public ICommand PlayCommand
{
  get
  {
    if (_playCommand == null) 
      _playCommand = new RelayCommand(player => this.play(player), param => this.canPlay); 
    return _playCommand;
  }
}
void play(object player)
{
  if (_player == null)
  {
    _player = (MediaElement)player;
    _player.MediaEnded += new RoutedEventHandler((s, e) =>
    {
      if (canPlayNext)
        playNext();
    });
  }

  _player.Play();  
}
```

...but I am still open for other ideas.